# How delete object by sending query to Session.Delete(...) in Nhibernate 3.3.3.4001

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following block of code which should ultimately delete a record.

```
long id = 81;
SessionInstance.Delete("from Core.Domain.Model.Person as obj where obj.Id =:id", id, NHibernateUtil.Int64);
```

But after upgrade Nhibernate version to 3.3.3.4001, this code has a exception by this message :

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Why?

Comment: Please add the C# code that deals with `Core.Domain.Model.Person`'s CRUD

Comment: From which version do you upgrade?

Comment: Strange one, I assume you have tried combos of `from Person where Id =:id` and `from Core.Domain.Model.Person where Id =:id`

Comment: Old Version was 3.1 and my problem is not `Person` because by  following change my problem is resolved : `SessionInstance.Delete("from Core.Domain.Model.Person as obj where obj.Id =" + id.ToString())`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use positional parameters (which you need to), the syntax is a bit different:

```
session.Delete("from Product p where p.ProductId = ?", id, NHibernateUtil.Int32);
```