# Attach an object to a session

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate

I'm trying to fix a bug in some legacy code. The code is trying to delete an object (a row) from the database. The Session, however, sometimes does not contain the object and throws an exception. I've added the test to see if the Session contains the object and then try various things to get the object into the Session, but no success thus far. Can you suggest what else I can try?

This code has implemented nHibernate Session very poorly in that it does not follow the Unit of Work ethic. The application creates one session when it starts and uses that session throughout the life of the application. Nothing I can do about this (other than a complete rewrite, in which case I would abandon nHibernate anyway).

```
using (ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        if (Session.Contains(object))
        {
            Session.Delete(object);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        else // new code, Session does not contain object
        {
            try
            {
                //Session.Close();
                //Session.Dispose();
                //Session.Disconnect();
                Session.Merge(object);
                Session.Save(object); // this does something
                Session.Lock(object, LockMode.Upgrade); // .Write in invalid mode
                Session.Update(object);
                using (ITransaction transaction2 = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    // this code executes with no error but does not delete the row from the database
                    Session.Delete(object);
                    transaction2.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception exception)
            {
                string message2 = exception.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(message2, "Delete() Try it again ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
}
    catch (System.Exception exception)
    {
        if (transaction != null)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try to delete in a different way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762358/1162077

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This seems to be an improvement. It deletes the row and also throws an exception. No way you can tell though, something idiosyncratic in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the object from the session first?

```
using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var persisted = Session.Get<SomeType>(object.Id); //object will be loaded if not already in the session
    Session.Delete(persisted);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: `Get` hits the database or session cache to retrieve the entity data. If the entity exists it will be returned. Otherwise `null` will be returned.